# StartCoroutine and IEnumerator (Unity 3D)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, ienumerator

This is my code

```
public void myFuntion(){
     JsonFx.Json.JsonWriter writer =new JsonFx.Json.JsonWriter();
     string jsondata2=writer.Write(fps);
     WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
     form.AddField("facprodstrans", jsondata2);
     string url="127.0.0.1/few/get_trans.php"; 
     www = new WWW(url,form);
     StartCoroutine(WaitForRequest(www));
     print ("<<<<<<<<<<<<<"+fpts.time_remaining);
 }
 IEnumerator WaitForRequest(WWW www){ 
     yield return www;
     string facpdata = www.text;
     JsonFx.Json.JsonReader reader = new JsonFx.Json.JsonReader ();
     fpts = reader.Read<FactoryProdTransS> (facpdata);
     print(">>>>>>>>>>>>>"+fpts.time_remaining);
 }
```

The print statement in the function 'myFunction' executes before the print statement in the IEnumerator, due to which it prints the old value first and the updated value afterwards, can not figure out why.

Comment: Is right.
The coroutine is another task and your coroutine is waiting for the www request be completed not stopping "myfunction"

Comment: hi @joreldraw no, that's wrong.  you're thinking of "yield return"

Comment: No, you are running 2 task, and this is only a run condition. Yield return of course delay your print line in the coroutine.

Comment: You are confusing

`StartCoroutine(WaitForRequest(www));`
with

 `yield return StartCoroutine(WaitForRequest(www));`
They are totally and completely different.

Answer (score 3):

MyFunction starts, it hits a StartCoroutine which is a method so it jumps there.
At that point MyFunction is on hold.

Unity does a bit of its own that few are actually aware since it happens on the c++ side. Somehow you could think it places the method on a coroutine list.

It starts running what is inside WaitForRequest until a yield is found. The yield is expected because of the return type IEnumerator.

When the yield is found, it quits the coroutine and gets back to where it left off, so back to MyFunction and continues right after StartCoroutine. In your case it prints.

Next frame, Unity checks that hypothetical list of coroutine to see if some were left, in your case it finds the WaitForRequest. It goes back in there where it quit priorly, the yield return www; . The program consults if the www is done and if not, does the same as previous frame. If the www is done, it skips the yield and continue with all your json parsing. At the end of the coroutine, I would assume the compiler searches for that method on the coroutine list and removes it so it won't happen again.

If you need an action to be performed once a coroutine is done you need to pass a delegate:

```
void OnComplete(){ Debug:Log("Done"); }

IEnumerator WaitForRequest(Action onComplete){ 
     WWW www = new WWW(url);
     yield return www;
     string facpdata = www.text;
     JsonFx.Json.JsonReader reader = new JsonFx.Json.JsonReader ();
     fpts = reader.Read<FactoryProdTransS> (facpdata);
     print(">>>>>>>>>>>>>"+fpts.time_remaining);
     onComplete();
 }
```

If you need to get result from your coroutine, it is also better to pass a delegate:

```
IEnumerator WaitForRequest(Action<string> onComplete){ 
     WWW www = new WWW(url);
     yield return www;
     string facpdata = www.text;
     JsonFx.Json.JsonReader reader = new JsonFx.Json.JsonReader ();
     fpts = reader.Read<FactoryProdTransS> (facpdata);
     print(">>>>>>>>>>>>>"+fpts.time_remaining);
     onComplete(www.text);
 }

void Start(){
    string text= null;
    StartCoroutine(WaitForRequest(result=> text = result));
}
```

Comment: probably a coroutine list not a stack? a stack would suggest you can pop coroutines off the top of the stack.

Comment: Yep, stack may not be the best example there. Hence the "hypothetical". But I meant stack as a generic container. Will change for list.

Comment: **"MyFunction starts, it hits a StartCoroutine which is a method so it jumps there. At that point MyFunction is on hold."** That is **totally wrong**, you may have made a typo, Everts.  When you `StartCoroutine(blah)` it specifically puts the coroutine on the runloop, and **keeps going**.  You may be thinking of "yield return StartCoroutine(blah)" which puts the coroutine on the runloop, and waits there until that coroutine is known to be finished.